# Error Deleting GCP Project

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I am trying to delete a GCP Project in my account, but I am facing repeated errors. If I try to delete is from gcloud command line, I get the following error.

```
ERROR: (gcloud.projects.delete) FAILED_PRECONDITION: active child resource
- '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.PreconditionFailure
  violations:
  - description: active child resource
    subject: services/56578916268
- '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ResourceInfo
  resourceName: projects/XXXXX
  resourceType: PROJECT
```

If I try to delete from the portal, I get this

[image: error]

This number is random and changes from time to time. I also deleted the Cloud Endpoints as suggested by this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59357139/when-i-shut-down-a-gcp-project-i-receive-an-unknown-error-with-a-tracking-numbe)

Comment: Considering the error message, it is most likely that you have an active child under this project. In Cloud Console, could you check Endpoints > Services. If all the services are deleted there then the project can be deleted.

Comment: I deleted the endpoints already(as mentioned in the post). Are there any other kinds of child resources?

Comment: Another possibility I can think of is [Tenant Projects](https://cloud.google.com/service-infrastructure/docs/manage-tenant-projects) or other flex resources.

Comment: For security reason, please sanitize your question [it contains your project number].

Comment: Thanks, @danyL. However, now that you mention it, is there a way to delete it completely? Someone can go to the previous version and see the sensitive information.

Comment: As for your other comment, I don't have any tenancy project. However, one thing needs to be mentioned. I deleted the cloud endpoint recently. Which means it's still in the recovery period. Can that be a reason?

Comment: Regarding the deletion of edits you can always check out this [post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284113/permanently-delete-edits). Also, I wouldn’t dismiss the possibility of the recently deleted cloud endpoint being the source of not being able to delete the project. If you have access to do it, I would recommend opening a [support case](https://cloud.google.com/support/) with GCP as they should have the tools to see what’s preventing the project from being deleted.

Comment: OR You could create a private issue using [issue-tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#issue_reports).

Comment: Agree with @Digil, everyone has billing support, they aren't technical but something simple like "I want to delete my project and billing account linked to it" should be fine.

As for me, I would check if your project has any "Shared VPC" or to run the same gcloud command but with "--log-http" flag, perhaps a message stating why this wasn't possible is available there.